# length function of a coxeter group with respect to two different simple systems are equal or not?

Tags: lie-algebras

Is there any relation between length function of a coxeter group with respect to two different simple systems as two simple systems are weyl conjugates of one another?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you are asking (because I do not know what a "simple system" is), but here is a general fact. Given a group $W$ with two finite generating sets $S_1,S_2$ and their associated length functions $L_1$ and $L_2$, if $K$ is the maximum of $L_1(s), L_2(s)$ over all $s \in S_1 \cup S_2$ then $L_1(w)/K \le L_2(w) \le K L_1(w)$ for all $w \in W$.

Comment: As David Speyer notes, this can't be so, for fairly obvious reasons. But one's feeling that there is some "metric object" that is independent of generators is correct, namely, the "gallery-distance" on the associated Coxeter complex. The word-length is the gallery-distance from the _distinguished_ chamber (reflections through whose sides are the given generators), to its image under the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To supplement what David Speyer and Paul Garrett have written, I'd emphasize that the question itself is faulty: the terminology involved in "two simple systems are weyl conjugates of one another" doesn't make sense here.   Whenever one speaks of a *Coxeter group* one is implicitly referring to a pair $(W,S)$ consisting of a group $W$ and a specified set $S$ of generators, along with certain explicit relations among those generators.   Only when you fix this data do you get a definite *length function* (relative to $S$) for $W$.

The tag "lie-algebras" already indicates some fuzziness here: there is no Lie algebra and no Weyl group.  Appropriate tags include "gr.group-theory" and "coxeter-groups"  As David's example indicates, even for simple Lie algebras and their Weyl groups, the Weyl group as a Coxeter group may admit multiple unrelated presentations.  And even if one requires $S$ to be a set of simple reflections in the sense of Lie theory, any root can be a simple root and have length 1 relative to some choice of $S$.   So I'm not sure what the question is really about(?)

Comment: @Jim: Things are actually even more interesting, since one can have two Coxeter systems $(W_1,S_1), (W_2,S_2)$, where $W_1$ is isomorphic to $W_2$ as an abstract group, but that there is no isomorphism of Coxeter systems. Thus, the entire premise of $S_1$ being conjugate to $S_2$ is false. On the other hand, in many cases, Coxeter groups are "rigid", see e.g. http://perso.uclouvain.be/pierre-emmanuel.caprace/papers_pdf/2sph_rigid.pdf 

Comment: @Jim actually the question is as follows,how the length function of elements of weyl group are related with respect to two different simple systems?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the question in the title is "no". Let $W=S_3$. Then the transpositions $\{ (12), (23) \}$ form a simple system and $\{ (12), (13) \}$ form another. The length of $(13)$ is $3$ in the first system and $1$ in the second.

As to the question "is there any relation?": Well, they are equal mod $2$. Also, as Lee Mosher says, they are within a constant factor of each other; that fact is only interesting for infinite Coxeter groups.

I suspect that there isn't any more to say, but it is always hard to be sure that there isn't some other relation between two things.